# How can i do a cast from a java.lang.Object to float?

Tags: java

My friend is using Eclipse and doesn't have any problem with this lines:

```
float secOp = (float) computingStack.pop();
float firstOp = (float) computingStack.pop();
```

I'm using Netbeans and gives an error in both lines, says that the types are not convertible. I tried to use `valueOf()` and `parseFloat`, but any was useful. I'm using generic data for my stack.

Comment: Do you have different java development versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't cast from object to primitive type. Did you try floatValue()?

```
float secOp  =  ((Float)computingStack.pop()).floatValue();
```

Regards